# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. with new Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, signature

I am developing an Angular2 app which shows log messages from a NodeJS server. I transport these messages over SocketIO, which I then dump into an Observable.

```
export class AuctionService {
  ...
  getMessages() {
    let logObservable = new Observable(observer => {
      this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
        if (!this.started) {
          this.started = true;
        }
        observer.next(data);
      });
    });
    return logObservable;
  }
```

this piece of code however, results into an error message:

`Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target`
which occurs at the line and column where `new Observable(` starts.

This code worked when I used Angular2 RC3, and broke since I updated to the latest stable version. Anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Usage of AuctionService.getMessages():

```
export class LogComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.auctionServiceConnection = this.auctionService.getMessages().subscribe(message => {
      this.messages.unshift(message);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that its because you are trying to return some incorrect stuff to he new Observable(). You don't need to return the `this.socket.disconnect()`.

try this:

```
    return new Observable(observer =>
    {
        this.socket.on('message', (data) =>
        {
            if (!this.started)
            {
                this.started = true;

            }
            observer.next(data);
            this.socket.disconnect()
        });
    }):
```

Comment: I removed the `return () => {
    this.socket.disconnect();
  }
` codeblock, because I indeed didn't need it. Still get the same error though.

Comment: Well if that the case there is nothing wrong with the code you provided. Could be something wrong with whatever uses `logObservable`.

Comment: I edited my question with my current implementation.

Comment: Had a look and everything looks fine, try changing to an explicit return. Also if you have updated @angular to one of the newer version make sure you have updated typescript in your package.json to version 2. Its probably a typescript error rather than one with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by first updating the angular-cli package used from `angular-cli` to `@angular/cli`. Then I create a new Angular2 project.

I agree with @run-yards that it must have been an issue with my dependencies.